# How to create mysagepay test account

Tags: opayo, magento-1.9

i have searched a lot but only got following login url for sagepay test account.

https://test.sagepay.com/mysagepay/login.msp

Can any one please help me from where i can create account to log in at above screen.

I have already created simulator account at

[simulator account](https://test.sagepay.com/Simulator/)

Answer (score 4):

To use this test sagepay login you need a normal sagepay payment gateway / merchant account or have a MySagePay account. This test URL is given to clients who have access to the live side for their day to day transactions.

If you have an account with Sage you can get them to set up the test environment for you.

Comment: Thank you haxtbh. i will ask my client for that

Answer (score -3):

create mysagepay test account

http://www.sagepay.co.uk/sign-up-for-beta-testing